# How could I load double quotation from c# and show it on sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have providing one field on c# and run it on sql, the problem is on string that I post to sql, I have double quotation, and it goes to sql with \", how could I solve it

```
string url = @" '<a href=""/p?geoId='+Geo.GeoId+'"">'+Geo.Name+'</a>';
//note: url can be like this and isn't matter on result
//string url = " '<a href=\"/p?geoId='+Geo.GeoId+'\">'+Geo.Name+'</a>';

string filterExpression=string.Format("SELECT Geo.Count as c,{0} as url from Geo ", url);

IQueryable<GeoDto> geoResult =  _entities.Database.SqlQuery<GeoDto>(filterExpression).AsQueryable();

return geoResult ;
```

But on result I see \", I looking for only double quotation result(without **\**)

Comment: But why you add `\"`. I dont see any use here

Comment: @Tushar: because tag of **href** needs double quotation, and on c# can't add it without "" or \"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`href` attribute can use single quotation.
You could try

```
string url = "'<a href=''/p?geoId='+Geo.GeoId+'''>'+Geo.Name+'</a>'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
string url = " '<a href=\"\"/p?geoId='+Geo.GeoId+'\"\">'+Geo.Name+'</a>' ";
```

Without the `@` escape.

Comment: Here is the result and it's wrong because I see it double now: <a href=\"\"/p